# Webpack 2 - file-loader [path] options

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-file-loader

Im using webpacks file-loader to output a bunch of compiled html files from a folder of pug templates.

I want to put the html files in the output directory, into the same folder structure they were in when they were in the source `/pug/` folder, minus the pug folder itself.

For example if in the `/pug/` folder, one of the files was `/pug/layouts/index.pug`, and another was in `/pug/templates/main/index.pug`, Im trying to make the outputted html files be sent to `/dist/layouts/index.html` and `/dist/templates/main/index.html`

Im using `file-loader?name=[path][name].html` but that results in files such as `/dist/pug/layouts/index.html` - note the **pug** folder. I cant work out how to get rid of it, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the file-loader accepts a `context=./path` query parameter

So this works `"file-loader?name=[path][name].html&context=./pug"`